# How to select rows with str.startswith containing more than 1 string values?

Tags: pandas, string, slice, startswith

I have this data, which is sorted in ascending order by codes in the string format (9-1-83...61-90.0100..).

```
array(['61-86.0100/32.0076B', '61-86.0100/32.0066', '61-86.0100/32.0031',
       '61-85.0100/45.0807', '61-85.0100/32.0066', '61-85.0100/32.0031',
       '61-84.0100/45.0807', '61-84.0100/32.0076B', '61-84.0100/32.0066',
       '61-84.0100/32.0031', '61-83.0100/32.0066', '61-83.0100/32.0031',
       '61-82.0100/32.0066', '61-82.0100/32.0031', '61-81.0100/45.0807',
       '61-81.0100/32.0066', '61-81.0100/32.0031', '61-80.0100',
       '61-8-47', '61-8-27', '61-8-127', '61-63.0600', '61-63.0500',
       '61-63.0100', '61-5-21', '61-5-20', '61-5-19', '61-5-18',
       '61-47.0000/47.0108', '61-45.0000/45.0800', '61-45.0000',
       '61-4-38', '61-4-37', '61-4-35', '61-4-33', '61-4-32',
       '61-14-452(2)', '61-14-176', '61-14-175', '61-130.0000/130.0500',
       '61-130.0000/130.0400', '61-130.0000/130.0300',
       '61-122.0100/32.0066', '61-121.0100/32.0066',
       '61-120.0100/32.0066', '61-118.0100/32.0066',
       '61-116.0100/32.0076B', '61-116.0100/32.0031',
       '61-115.0100/32.0031', '61-114.0100/32.0031', '61-114.0100',
       '61-111.0100/32.0066', '61-105.0100/32.066',
       '61-105.0100/32.0076B', '61-104.0100', '61-102.0100/32.0066',
       '61-101.0100/32.0066', '61-100.0100', '22-3-3', '22-3-2',
       '22-2-97(b)', '22-2-97', '22-2-96(a)', '22-2-96', '22-2-94',
       '22-2-93', '22-2-92', '22-2-91', '22-2-88(b)', '22-2-88(a)',
       '22-2-88', '22-2-87(a)', '22-2-87', '22-2-86', '22-2-85',
       '22-2-84(b)(3)', '22-2-84(b)(1)', '22-2-84(a)(1)(2)(4)',
       '22-2-84(a)', '22-2-84 (DO NOT USE ', '22-2-83a', '22-2-83(d)',
       '22-2-83(c)', '22-2-83(b)', '22-2-83(a)(b)(c)', '22-2-83',
       '22-2-61', '22-2-56', '22-2-55', '22-2-53', '22-2-49(d)',
       '22-2-49(c)', '22-2-49(b)', '22-2-49(a)', '22-2-49', '22-2-45',
       '22-2-44', '22-2-43', '22-2-42(b)', '22-2-42', '22-2-41(b)',
       '22-2-41', '22-2-38', '22-2-25', '22-2-23', '22-2-22(a)',
       '22-2-22', '22-2-21(b)', '22-2-21(a)', '22-2-20', '22-2-19',
       '22-2-18', '22-2-17(a)', '22-2-17', '22-2-16', '20180901',
       '20160901', '20130901', '19850901', '19840901', '19830901',
       '19450901', '19420901', '19410901'], dtype=object)
```

I can select the rows beginning with a part of the code by

```
filter=df.code.str.startswith('61-8')
df[filter].head()
```

which gives me several rows like this:

```
          code              description
ticket_id       
182815  61-86.0100/45.0807  Open Storage/ Residential/ Commercial Vehicles (R6)
134931  61-86.0100/32.0076B Open Storage/ Residential/ Refuse (R6)
136938  61-86.0100/32.0076B Open Storage/ Residential/ Refuse (R6)
134930  61-86.0100/32.0066  Open Storage/ Residential/ Inoperable Vehicles (R6)
245596  61-86.0100/32.0066  Open Storage/ Residential/ Inoperable Vehicles (R6)
```

How can I select two different strings, for example, '61-8' and '61-9'?
I want to combine them into fewer groups.

I have tried:

```
df.code.str.startswith('61-90|61-96')
df[(df.code.str.startswith('61-96'))| (df.code.str.startswith('61-90'))]
```

which did not work, giving me an empty dataframe.

Comment: Try `new_df = df.loc[(df['code'].str.startswith('61-8')) | (df['code'].str.startswith('61-9'))]` The `.loc` might make the difference.

Comment: use a `tuple` : ``df.loc[df.code.str.startswith(("61-90", "61-96"))]``. pass in as many entries as you want into the tuple. [startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) uses tuples for multiple selections

Comment: Both of your answers solved my problem! thank you.